# Centinel API endpoint URL is not configured properly. Magento 1.8 exception

Tags: php, api, magento

When I am using the the saved CC payment method im magnento 1.8.1 it's throwing this exception.

```
exception 'Exception' with message 'Centinel API endpoint URL is not configured properly.' in app/code/core/Mage/Centinel/Model/Api.php:185
```

Please let me know what is this error and why I am getting this.

Answer (score 1):

This may be late to answer, but could be helpful to someone else.

Try disabling the "3D Secure Card Validation" while using test credit card methods in Magento. It should cure the exception and remove any errors on frontend.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had Paypal Payflow Pro enabled in the Test mode in Magento admin with **3D Secure Card Validation** set to Yes.

When I set the **3D Secure Card Validation** to *No* the problem solved.